# How to connect to api using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

newbie here in Restful API.  How can I connect to the API? I've tried several ways on how to connect it but nothing seems to work. I provided the restful API connection codes below but I don't know how to connect it. I have provided my codes below. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Views:

```
<form action="<?=base_url('account/dologin');?>" method="post"> 

     
<!--  login   -->

     <form id="doLogin">

  
        <div class="input-group mb-3 dropShadow" style="padding:35px 35px 5px 45px;">
          <input type="text" class="signinrow" name="formUsername" placeholder="Username">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text" style="background:transparent; border: none;">
              <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-4 dropShadow" style="padding:1px 35px 25px 45px;">
          <input type="password" class="signinrow" name="formPassword" placeholder="Password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text" style="background:transparent; border: none;">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="text-bold text-sm afterLoginForm text-center" >
      <p class=" mb-2" style="font-size: 18px;">

       
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recoAcc" type="button" class="dropShadow bebas" ><u>I forgot my password </u></a><br> 

        </p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
  <div>
    <button id="btnSubmit"> Sign In</button>
     <img id="submit_preloader" src="<?=pubPath('/assets/imgs/order_button_preloader.gif'); ?>" alt="Processing..." style=" display:none;" id="reg_preloader2" >
     </div>
      </form>
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function dologin()
    {
      
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
      
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $username = $ci->input->post('formUsername');
        $password= $ci->input->post('formPassword');
        $ipAddress =$ip;
        $baseSessionID = $ip.$username;
     
       

        $url = "https://blabla.com/Auth/login";

        
        $data_array = array('username' => $username,'password' => $password,'baseSessionID' => $baseSessionID,'ipAddress' => $ipAddress);

        
        $data = http_build_query($data_array);
        $data1 = array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Auth-Key: simplerestapi',
            'Client-Service: frontend-client'

            
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data1);
        $reply=curl_exec($ch);

        

        
        $decode = json_decode($reply,true);

        
        $username1=$decode['message'];
        $password1=$decode['password'];
        $userfailed=$decode['mali'];

        
        $_SESSION["username"] = $this->input->post("formUsername");
        if($username1 ==='Successfully login.'||$password1 ==='Successfully login.'){       //Login success
            redirect(site_url('account/dashboard'), $data);

            
        }elseif($userfailed ==='failed username'){                                          //Wrong Username
            echo '<script>alert("Wrong Password or Username!");</script>';
            redirect(site_url(), $data);

            
            curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: where is auth/login?

Comment: Hello, thank you. I added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code which is tested with the wordpress API and codeigniter 3. You'll need to amend the $opts array.

$method would be post, get, put ...

$url the api url ...

$opts = array('https'=>array('method'=>"GET",'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer $token"));

```
public function CallAPI($method, $url, $opts = false)
{
$curl = curl_init();

switch ($method)
{
    case "POST":
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        if ($opts)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $opts);
        break;
    case "PUT":
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
        break;
    default:
        if ($opts)
            $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($opts));
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

return $result;
}
```

// The following is your code but slightly amended to change the header and suggest Authorization which is commented out. I also removed some unnecessary curl. I changed your $data_array to include the header but try it in its original form as well but with content-Type as application/json.

```
 $url = "https://blabla.com/Auth/login";
    
 $data_array = array('username' => $username,'password' => 
 $password,'baseSessionID' => $baseSessionID,'ipAddress' => $ipAddress, 
'https' => array('header' => 'Content-Type: application/json','Auth-Key: 
 simplerestapi', 'Client-Service: frontend-client'));

    $data = http_build_query($data_array);
    /*
    $data1 = array(
        //'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Type: application/json', 
        'Auth-Key: simplerestapi',
        //'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("app_key:app_secret")
        'Client-Service: frontend-client'
    );
    */
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data1);

    $reply=curl_exec($ch);
    
    if($e = curl_error($ch)){
        echo $e;
    }else{
        
        echo $decode = json_decode($reply,true);
    }
    
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. How can I connect my login to API?

Comment: You should be able to connect using the methodology I've added to my answer. This is a good chrome extension to view nicely formatted json in your browser by the way - JSON Viewer

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll work on it now. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: No worries let me know how you get on.

Comment: I updated my codes. It is already connected to API. However, do you have any suggestions on my controller? (For improvement or something).

Comment: I'll have a look at some stuff I've done in the past and see if I can see anything worth implementing for you. In the meantime can you mark the answer as correct please?